# Append text when mousePressed() is false

Tags: java, arrays, processing

I want to make the text show on screen when mousePressed() is false every 3 seconds, I set a boolean "whether" in mousePressed() function and when it quals false I get strings from a text file. But it seems like my logic is wrong. DO anyone know the problem?

```
Zoog[]zoog = new Zoog[1];
float count=0;
int xpos =0;
int ypos =0;
String message="haha";
String newone="";
String t="\n";
int ntextsize = 20;
int nopacity =200;
int thistime = 0;
int thiscount = 0;
String[]lines;
//Zoog zoog;
boolean whether;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
    xpos = int(random(width/2-200, width/2+40));
  ypos = int(random(height/2, height/2-40));
  zoog[0] = new Zoog(xpos,ypos,message,nopacity);
}

void draw(){
  background(255,255,255);

  for(int i=0; i<zoog.length; i++){
//    if(millis()-thistime>4000){
//     zoog[i].disappear(); 
//    }
    zoog[i].jiggle();
    zoog[i].display();


  }
  whether = false;
  lines = loadStrings("data.txt");
  if(whether!=true){
  createnew(int(random(width)), int(random(height)), lines[int(random(lines.length))],150);
  }
}


void mousePressed(){
  whether = true;
   count = count + 1;
 // int thiscount = 0;
  if(count%3 ==0){
    xpos=int(random(30, width-30));
    ypos=int(random(10, height-10));

  }
  else{
    ypos = ypos+50;
  }


 nopacity = int(random(100,255));

 createnew(xpos,ypos,message,nopacity);

}

void createnew(int xxpos, int yyos, String mmessage, int nnopacity){

  Zoog b = new Zoog(xpos,ypos,message,nopacity);
 zoog =(Zoog[]) append(zoog,b);

}
```

The function corresponding to my question is:

```
 lines = loadStrings("data.txt");
  if(whether!=true){
  createnew(int(random(width)), int(random(height)), lines[int(random(lines.length))],150);
  }
}
```

and

```
void createnew(int xxpos, int yyos, String mmessage, int nnopacity){

  Zoog b = new Zoog(xpos,ypos,message,nopacity);
 zoog =(Zoog[]) append(zoog,b);

}
```

Comment: not related exactly to the question, but you should only load the text file once, in your setup()...

Answer (score 0):

As you call `whether = true` just before testing for it in `if(whether!=true)` it will always be true and test is not going to evaluate to true, so code inside block will not run. mousePressed() is called once when mouse is pressed, run this code so understand how it works:

```
boolean b;
void setup(){frameRate(10);}
void draw(){ b = false; println("in draw " + b);}
void mousePressed(){b = true;println("in mousePressed " + b);}
```

see? But there is a field (a "default" var) in processing called mousePressed (without parenthesis) that would behave just as you need, just test for it in draw, running the same code added the mousePressed field in draw will show you what i mean:

```
boolean b;

void setup() {
  frameRate(10);
}

void draw() { 
  b = false; 
  println("in draw " + b); 
  if (mousePressed)println("i'm pressed");
}

void mousePressed() {
  b = true;
  println("im mousePressed " + b);
}
```

You could also create your own boolean and set it to true in mousePressed() and to false in mouseReleased(). With the same effect.

[EDIT] Just occurred to me, yet another way... if you change the call in draw as follows it should work as well:

```
 lines = loadStrings("data.txt");
  if(whether!=true){
  createnew(int(random(width)), int(random(height)), lines[int(random(lines.length))],150);
   whether = false;// move this here
  }
```